# How to I remove the "This file has limited permissions. You may not have access to some features. View Permissions" notification on protected PDF?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pdf, notifications

Is there a way to remove the "This file has limited permissions. You may not have access to some features. View Permissions" notification that pops up when viewing a protected pdf in browser?

I am creating a website in WordPress and have made a page with an embedded pdf. I have removed the toolbar but still get the above notification whenever a user loads the page. Is there a way to remove this notification without removing any of the protections on the PDF? Or would I be better off finding a plugin that can protect the pdf without throwing the error. I added all the protections via Adobe. See the picture below.

[Protected PDF Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3iNE.png)

Comment: Please attach the error text instead of image

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I am going to try out rebuilding the PDF as a rogue and see what happens. Also, for clarification, there is not error being thrown. Only the notification shown in the image because of the protections on the file.